# How to make customize delete button on UITableViewCell on iOS 11

Tags: xcode, uitableview

This is code which can appear UITableViewCell delete button with some custom things (color, image) but after when i updated on iOS 11 this code didn't work and instead of my custom button i have just red button. How i am understand apple change key "UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton" again. Maybe you know how to fix this issue?

```
- (UIView*)recursivelyFindConfirmationButtonInView:(UIView*)view
{
    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) {
        // iOS 8+ code here
        for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) {

            if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) rangeOfString:@"UITableViewCellActionButton"].location != NSNotFound)
                return subview;

            UIView *recursiveResult = [self recursivelyFindConfirmationButtonInView:subview];
            if(recursiveResult)
                return recursiveResult;
        }
    }

    else{
        // Pre iOS 8 code here
        for(UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            if([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) isEqualToString:@"UITableViewCellDeleteConfirmationButton"]) return subview;
            UIView *recursiveResult = [self recursivelyFindConfirmationButtonInView:subview];

            if(recursiveResult) return recursiveResult;

        }
    }
    return nil;

}

-(void)overrideConfirmationButtonColor
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        UIView *confirmationButton = [self recursivelyFindConfirmationButtonInView:self];
        if(confirmationButton)
        {
            self.buttonConfirm = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 15, 90, 90)];
            self.buttonConfirmAnimation = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 15, 40, 40)];


            self.buttonConfirmAnimation.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"heartWh"];

            confirmationButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"patternPlist@2x"]];

            [confirmationButton addSubview:self.buttonConfirmAnimation];

            [confirmationButton bringSubviewToFront:self.buttonConfirm];

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the same issue - since iOS 11.x the proposed solution doesn't work anymore. I noticed Apple is no longer using a UIButton for the delete button, but instead an UIView named `UITableViewCellEditControl` and this view has two subviews.

These two subviews are in fact of type UIImageView, one with a colored image of the delete icon and one with a gray version (I guess some kind of effect / shadow). You can still modify these images, e.g. set their tintColors or change the image completely.

Unfortunately there are now two additional problems:

1. `UITableViewCellEditControl` is also used in case your editing style is `none`, i.e. it could be the selection control (the empty dot / circle). It doesn't seem possible two distinguish these two usecases without using the actual editingStyle from the UITableView itself.
2. After you tap the delete control, it's image get's replaced by the original one from Apple. Using / Setting the UIImageView's highlighted image property as well, doesn't help. It seems there's some underlying logic going on in `UITableViewCellEditControl` that will implicitly reset the image to the original one.